# Rmd: print sometimes to document and sometimes to console

Tags: r, console, r-markdown

I compile an Rmd document (say `test.Rmd`) in R using

```r
>> library('rmarkdown');
>> rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd');
```

Here is a test document:

````
---
title: "Musterdokument für Rmd"
subtitle: "Testcase"
author:
- "Max Mustermann"
date: "2018-10-09"
output:
pdf_document:
editor_options:
chunk_output_type: console
---




# Introduction
This is a test document.

# My code
Here is a test R-script

```{r, test 1, eval=TRUE, results="show", echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=''}
options('digits'=6);

x <- runif(1);
print(x); # will be shown in the output document. How do I get it to display in the R-console too/instead?
```

```{r, test 2, eval=TRUE, results="hide", echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=''}
x <- runif(1);
print(x); # still doesn't work...
```
````

(I had to indent in this posting so that the ``` characters would not escape the code block.)

Sometimes I really want to have things print to the normal R-console *eg* menu-interaction or just ordinary print commands. But everything seems to go straight to the document. Is there a way to be able to do both?